# How can I use Class object in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I try to create a new Object of an Class at a click on a Button and want to store this Object in the vuex state. 
For Example, when a button is clicked, it calls the method "newMine()":

```
newMine() {
        this.$store.dispatch('setNewMine',"Iron")
      }
```

in the Store, i have this action:

```
import { Mine } from './modules/mine'
...
state: {
    mines:[]
  },
  mutations: {
    setNewMine(state,ore){
      state.mines.push(new Mine(ore))
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setNewMine({commit},ore){
      commit('setNewMine',ore)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getMines:(state) =>{
      return state.mines
    }
  }
```

the class "Mine" looks like this:

```
export default class Mine {
    constructor(id,wert){
        this.id = id
        this.wert = wert
    }
    get id(){
        return this.id
    }
      set id(id) {
        this.id = id
      }
      get wert(){
        return this.wert
      }
      set wert(wert) {
        this.id = wert
      }
  }
```

It should be really simple, but it still doesnt work, because i get the error message:

*[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _modules_mine__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Mine is not a constructor"*

Whats wrong here? Any help is welcomed, even if it without the store.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`import { Mine } from './modules/mine'` results in `Mine === undefined`, so it causes `is not a constructor` error when instantiated with `new`.

`export default class Mine {...}` is default export. So it needs to be imported as:

```
import Mine from './modules/mine'
```

Comment: tried without the brackets, but then i get this error message: "Error in v-on handler: "InternalError: too much recursion"

Comment: It's because of `id` member. You're getting/setting a property that calls a getter/setter of itself, this results in recursion. In case you want to provide getter/setter pair for `id` (this is an antipattern in this case because it doesn't differ from regular `this.id` access), there should be a private property,  `set id(id) {
        this._id = id
      }` and `get id(){
        return this._id
    }`.